# Which keyword I should use?

Tags: ddl, syntax, database-agnostic

I have two tables:

```
I1 (A, B, C)
I2 (A, C)
```

**I2** has some tuple of data that **I1** doesn't have.

Now I want to create a table **I3** that only has the data (A, C) that both exists in **I1** and **I2**.

- Which keyword I should use to create this table?
- Use intersect?

Comment: it is not clear from your post what you exactly want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24cc1e/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the combination `(a,c)` is unique in both table, then this is a case of a simple join plus a `create table as`

```
create table i3
as
select i1.a, i1.c
from i1
  join i2 on i2.a = i1.a and i2.c = i1.c;
```

If `(a,c)` is not unique you will have duplicates in the resulting table. This can be avoided by using the `intersect` operator:

```
create table i3
as
select a, c
from i1
intersect
select a,c
from i2;
```

---

Note that `create table ... as select` is ANSI SQL but some DBMS (e.g. SQL Server) don't follow the standard and use a different syntax to create a table based on a `select` statement.